# logical values for censored data matlab

Tags: matlab

I am relatively new to Matlab and have a question about creating a logical array in Matlab
Suppose I have the following data.  A contains actual values and B column denotes U as undetected

A    B

2    U

4    U

5

6    U

6

7    U

8

I would like to create a logical array such as undetected values get a 1 and else 0.  Thus the c column would look some thing like this:

C = 1 1 0 1 0 1 0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How is this data represented in Matlab?  Is this a cell array, two separate numeric arrays?  The syntax will vary slightly depending on the specifics.   --  It would be helpful to add to small code snippet.

Comment: I import the data using textscan so it is a cell array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is a cell array (we'll call it `data`), then I typically use `cellfun` for this sort of work.

```
C = cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && ischar(x) && strcmp(x,'U') , data(:,2))
```

This defines an anonymous function which returns `true` for any input which is (1) not empty, (2) a character array and (3) has a value of 'U' and.  It calls that function on each element in the second column of `data`, and returns it in an array `C`.

I like that it fits a single operation on a single line.  It is easy to read after you use the construction enough times (but perhaps not easy to read the first few times).

---

A more typical (and perhaps easier to understand) solution is to use a loop.

```
 C = logical(zeros(size(data,1),1));  %Always preallocate your results vector
 for ix = 1:size(data,1)
     curValue = data{ix,2}l
     C(ix) =  ~isempty(curValue ) && ischar(curValue ) && strcmp(curValue ,'U');
 end
```

---

Finally, it sounds like you may actually want your result back in your original cell array, in the third column.  That is a small change to the loop above, like so:

```
 for ix = 1:size(data,1)
     curValue = data{ix,2};
     data{ix,3} =  ~isempty(curValue) && ischar(curValue) && strcmp(curValue ,'U');
 end
```

---

*EDIT*

If your data is in a cell array of arrays (based on a recent comment), then try:

```
C = mydata{2} == 'U';
```

This extracts the character array, and compares each element to the character `'U'`.

Comment: I tried all 3 of your approaches. First one, output C=0.  Second one, output is still C=0.  Third one, output mydata = [7x1 double]    [7x1 char]    [0] (notice C is still 0 instead of something like 7x1 logical) Do you have any other suggestions to fix this?

Comment: `mydata = [7x1 double] [7x1 char] [0]` is a different form than I was assuming.  I'll add another option.

Answer (score 0):

You can not mix char arrays with logical values, but you can use the `strcmp` function. Suppose you have all this is one array called A (I'll note detected as 'D'):

```
A = [2,'U';...
     4,'U';...
     5,'D';...
     6,'U';...
     6,'D';...
     7,'U';...
     8,'D']

test = A(:,2);
C = zeros(size(A,1),1);
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    C(i) = strcmp(test(i),'U');
end
```

If you have an other way to mark the values as "detected", then you might be able to use logical, i.e.: detected values are values above 5.

```
C = (A(:,1) > 5);
```

Output would be:

```
C = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

Comment: Thank you Smash.  I tried your code but all I got for C is a number 1. I would like get a vector of 1 and 0. The second approach you suggested is only good if you have 1 censored data.  Here I have a multiple censored values in 1 dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to Pursuit answer, all you need to do is:

```
C = mydata{2}=='U';
```

You should show how your data is organized in the question.

Comment: Thank you Pursuit and yuk for your time.  The code worked!!! Could you please explain what the following code means (for my sake of learning):   curValue = data{ix,2}; % why this curValue?   
               data{ix,3} =  ~isempty(curValue) && ischar(curValue) && strcmp(curValue ,'U');